# Using Linq to Filter a List of Objects based on a Condition

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, .net-core

I am solving an issue where I want to remove unwanted objects from a list `List<RegionData>` as a result of a **region name condition**.
As an entry input I receive `var data` , which contains a `List<CasesDto>`. One item `CasesDto` corresponds to all region-based data received on **one particular date**.

These are two of my classes that I am using as an example:

```
public class CasesDto
{    
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}

    public List<RegionData> Region {get; set;}
}
```

and

```
public class RegionData
{
    public string RegionName {get; set;}

    public int DailyActiveCases {get; set;}

    public int DeceasedToDate {get; set;}
}
```

This is the current output example (I only included two dates (= two CasesDto) for easy-to-view purpose) where *region* **is not** taken into consideration:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2021-05-22T00:00:00",
        "region": [
            {
                "regionName": "ce",
                "dailyActiveCases": 615,
                "deceasedToDate": 568
            },
            {
                "regionName": "kk",
                "dailyActiveCases": 170,
                "deceasedToDate": 197
            },
            {
                "regionName": "kp",
                "dailyActiveCases": 278,
                "deceasedToDate": 166
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-05-23T00:00:00",
        "region": [
            {
                "regionName": "ce",
                "dailyActiveCases": 613,
                "deceasedToDate": 570
            },
            {
                "regionName": "kk",
                "dailyActiveCases": 167,
                "deceasedToDate": 197
            },
            {
                "regionName": "kp",
                "dailyActiveCases": 277,
                "deceasedToDate": 166
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the output I would want if **regionName="ce"** is applied:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2021-05-22T00:00:00",
        "region": [
            {
                "regionName": "ce",
                "dailyActiveCases": 615,
                "deceasedToDate": 568
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-05-23T00:00:00",
        "region": [
            {
                "regionName": "ce",
                "dailyActiveCases": 613,
                "deceasedToDate": 570
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to solve this problem with **lambda functions**.

My attempt:

`data = data.ForEach(x => x.Region.Where(t => t.RegionName == region)).ToList();`

However, I receive a mismatch in return type. How can I access RegionData model and select only a region item (based on region identifier) that I want?

Comment: var filteredData = data.Where(t => t.Region.RegionName == region);

Comment: `var filtered = data.Where(x => x.Region.Any(t => t.RegionName == region));`

Comment: This does not work because t.Region is a List<RegionData>. It cannot find RegionName. It would work with t.Region[i].RegionName, however there is no index "i" to help us with this.

Comment: @JochemVanHespen your example compiled, however it did not work. It returned the same output as was the input. It didn't filter.

Comment: ow yes sorry I misread you want only the regions right? Not the CasesDTO

Comment: @JochemVanHespen That is correct. I only want certain region not entire list of regions within every CasesDTO.

Comment: Hmmm the thing is enumerating over a cases dto list will be neccessary the thing with `ForEach` is that it doesn't return anything so we'll probably need to maintain a list somewhere else. Is this a problem? since you're pointing out you want to use lambda functions, I kinda got this feeling you want to keep it as a oneliner

Comment: @JochemVanHespen Example above shows the JSON structure that I want when ```regionName == "ce"``` for example. I want entire CasesDTO but within them just 1 region instead of entire list. I hope that clarifies it.

Comment: @JochemVanHespen That is perfectly fine, we can use multiple lines as long as we keep it minimal to the best of the ability.

Comment: okay let me setup a dotnet fiddle

Comment: you'll probably end up checking the accepted answer but [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wpOZPP) you go, somewhat simplified example though

Comment: @JochemVanHespen Thank you very much, your answer in the snippet was perfect. Could you post your answer so I can approve it?

Comment: @Guide4Ever yes sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var cases = new List<CasesDto>{
        new CasesDto{
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Region = new List<RegionData> {
                new RegionData{
                    RegionName = "CE"
                },
                new RegionData{
                    RegionName = "DE"
                }
            }
        },
        new CasesDto{
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10),
            Region = new List<RegionData> {             
                new RegionData{
                    RegionName = "DE"
                }
            }
        }
    };
    
    
    var filteredCases = new List<CasesDto>();
    var regionName = "CE";
    cases.ForEach(c => {
        if(c.Region.Any(x => x.RegionName == regionName)){
            c.Region = c.Region.Where(x => x.RegionName == regionName).ToList();
            filteredCases.Add(c);
        }
    });
```

Somewhat simplified to save me some time. Using ForEach we enumerate over the list and check if we have a region with given regionnames. If so we filter the current list to only contain the correct regions and append this result to a new list.

Answer (score 0):

So you have an enumerable sequence of `CasesDtos` (plural noun), where every `CasesDto` (singular noun) has at least properties `Date` and `Region`.

Region is an enumerable sequence of `RegionDatas`. Every RegionData has several properties, among which a property `RegionName`.

I think you've described the following requirement:

> Requirement: given a string value for `regionName`, and a sequence of `CasesDtos`, give me the `Date` and the `RegionData` of every `CasesDto` that has at least one `RegionData` with a value for property `RegionName` that equals `regionName`.

You didn't tell what you want if a CasesDto has two RegionData with the correct RegionName:

```
string regionName = "CA";
var casesDto = new CasesDto
{
     Date = ...
     Region = new List<RegionData>()
     {
          new RegionData()
          {
              RegionName = "CA",
              ...
          },
          new RegionData()
          {
              RegionName = "CA",
              ...
          }
    }
}
```

casesDto has two RegionDatas with a matching RegionName. What do you want in your end result: only the Date and one of the RegionDatas? which one? Or do you want all RegionDatas with a matching RegionName?

Anyway, the solution is:

```
string regionName = "CA";
IEnumerable<CasesDto> casesDtos = ...

// from every CasesDto, make one object, containing the Date, and a property 
// Region, which contains only those RegionDatas that have a value for property 
// RegionName that equals regionName
var result = casesDtos.Select(casesDto => new
{
    Date = casesDto.Date,

    // keep only those Regions that have a matching RegionName:
    Region = casesDto.Region
        .Where(region => region.RegionName == regionName)
        .ToList(),
}

// From this selection, keep only those object that have at least one Region:
.Where(casesDto => casesDto.Region.Any());
```

In words: for every CasesDto in casesDtos, make one new object with two properties: the Date of the CasesDto, and a property Region which contains the RegionDatas of this CasesDto that have a matching RegionName. From this Select result, keep only those object that have at least one element in list Region.

Comment: Your answer also delivered the right result! Thank you! I've made a slight adjustment according to my needs but the logic is flawless. I've put ```new CasesDto``` instead of just ```new``` in ```var result``` variable so I bypassed the mismatch.