# Filter data by the current user's id C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, filtering, userid

I want to filter my data to show only the data created by the current user, only the stories they created, this is my code. I tried many options, I just don't know how to take the user's Id and how to filter the data with it.I am using the regular IdentityUser with their email,password validations,i have only added User class with only FullName property inside it,so the SignInManager and UserManager look like this. **EDIT****(*for anyone who needs it , you can get the current user's id with this line*** **'var userId = this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;'** .edited

```
@inject SignInManager<User> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<User>



public StoriesQueryServiceModel AllMine(string topicm, string searchterm, int currentpage, int storiesper,string userId)
{
    var storquery = this.data.Stories.AsQueryable();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(topicm))
    {
        storquery = storquery.Where(s => s.Genre.Name == topicm);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchterm))
    {
        storquery = storquery.Where(s => (s.Title + " " + s.Topic).ToLower().Contains(searchterm.ToLower())
                                          || s.StoryText.ToLower().Contains(searchterm.ToLower()));
    }

    var totstor = storquery.Count();

    var stories = storquery
                      .Skip((currentpage - 1) * storiesper)
                      .Take(storiesper)
                      .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
                      .Select(s => new StoriesServiceModel
                                       {
                                           Id = s.Id,
                                           Title = s.Title,
                                           StoryText = s.StoryText
                                       })
                      .ToList();

    var genresli = this.data
                       .Stories
                       .Select(s => s.Genre.Name)
                       .Distinct()
                       .OrderBy(st => st)
                       .ToList();

    return new StoriesQueryServiceModel
               {
                   TotalStories = totstor,
                   Genres = genresli,
                   CurrentPage = currentpage,
                   StoriesPerPage = storiesper,
                   Stories = stories
               };
}
```

Comment: Please update your model as well.

Comment: for anyone who needs it , you can get the current's user id with this line 'var userId = this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Linq to Filter a List of Objects based on a Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69614389/using-linq-to-filter-a-list-of-objects-based-on-a-condition)